# SQL show record when join has no records

Tags: sql, join

```
SELECT     tblProducts.productName, 
           tblProducts.basePrice, 
           tblProductOptions.optionDescription
FROM       tblProducts CROSS JOIN tblProductOptions
WHERE      (tblProducts.ID = 3) AND (tblProductOptions.ID = 5)
```

If `(tblProductOptions.ID = 5)` then it works, there is an option with ID = 5.  If it's `(tblProductOptions.ID = 99999)` then it returns nothing, as there is no option with ID = 99999.

I would like to modify the statement so that it still returns the product record if an invalid option ID is passed to it!  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `CROSS JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, and (because the WHERE limits the results to NON nulls) change your WHERE to be

```
WHERE (tblProducts.ID = 3) 
AND   (tblProductOptions.ID = 5 OR tblProductOptions.ID IS NULL)
```

Comment: **SELECT     tblProducts.productName, tblProducts.basePrice, tblProductOptions.optionDescription
FROM         tblProducts LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tblProductOptions ON tblProductOptions.ID = 9
WHERE     (tblProducts.ID = 3)** works great thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

A CROSS JOIN is a cartesian product .. probably not what you are looking for.
I would  suggest INNER JOIN instead